# All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names

Tags: neo4j

I create 4 nodes in Neo4j (v 2.3.1):

```
CREATE(e:CreditCard{number:"523442521542",name:"Cho",cvv:432,expiration:"09/20"})
CREATE(f:CreditCard{number:"423425234252",name:"Lee",cvv:524,expiration:"11/18"})
CREATE(g:DebitCard {number:"414273681234",name:"Jim",cvv:223,expiration:"12/19"})
CREATE(h:DebitCard {number:"451573681234",name:"Bob",cvv:413,expiration:"11/18"})
```

I attempt `UNION` operation:

```
MATCH(cc:CreditCard)
RETURN cc
UNION
MATCH(dc:DebitCard)
RETURN dc
```

I get error message:

> All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names (line 2, column 1 (offset: 31))
>   "UNION"

Why? All fields appear to match perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alias the names to match. Apparently `cc` and `dc` aren't seen as the same despite their matching column names.

```
MATCH(cc:CreditCard)
RETURN cc AS Card
UNION
MATCH(dc:DebitCard)
RETURN dc AS Card
```